# Python(Django) web site on ISPConfig3

Tags: python, django

Can I run both PHP and Python(Django) websites on one ISPConfig without some changes in code, just from ISPConfig on Fedora 14?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can follow this tuotorial, which explains that how you can accomplish this with the help of mod_python

http://www.howtoforge.com/embedding-python-in-apache2-with-mod_python-debian-ubuntu-fedora-centos-mandriva-opensuse

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to enable python in the domain you want to enable python while creating hosting account. You can edit the sites from control panel to enable python.